# What is <fieldsets/ > stands for?

Tags: module, ce-1.9.0.1, configuration

When I have gone through `Mage_Bundle` module in magento, I found this code snippet inside `app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml`.

```
<admin>
    <fieldsets>
        <catalog_product_dataflow>
            <is_in_stock>
                <product_type>
                    <bundle/>
                </product_type>
            </is_in_stock>
            <manage_stock>
                <product_type>
                    <bundle/>
                </product_type>
            </manage_stock>
        </catalog_product_dataflow>
    </fieldsets>
    ...
</admin>
```

What is this `<fieldsets />` stands for ? I have searched a lot. But every reference is describing about system fieldsets. Can anyone here describe, what is this for ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<fieldsets/>` node is custom and used differently in different modules.

In `Mage_Bundle` it is used to define the fields which have to be parsed while importing/exporting products via `Mage_Dataflow` (which is outdated and shouldn't be used).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then why that code appears in magento 1.9 fresh installation, if it had been deprecated ?

Comment: No, why do you think it should be deprecated?